# MarkerClusterer GoogleMaps: Just update counter instead of redrawing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using **Marker Clusterer** to display the amount of "markers" in an area in my Google Maps Web Application.

But: Every time a flag appears / disappears, it seems that the Clusterer gets completely redrawn instead of just updated the counter inside.

I understand this behaviour because of the different colors, sizes etc.

> But what can i do to prevent this?

Do i have to prevent the different stylings so the Clusterer stays the "same", or what can i do to just update the number inside the circle?

**I have thousands of markers, every one appears/and disappears, so i just want to have a steady circle with a number inside.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is option `nodraw` which can be set to `true` and redraw won't be performed:

Adds a marker to the clusterer and redraws if needed:

```
addMarker(marker:google.maps.Marker, opt_nodraw:boolean)
```

Add an array of markers to the clusterer:

```
addMarkers(markers:Array.<google.maps.Marker>, opt_nodraw:boolean)
```